# VSTO accessing date of message as entered in the header

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, mapi

in VSTO I want to access the date of a sent message as it appears in the recipient clients header. Sent Items return an empty transport header (for obvious reasons) however I can't find a date to match the date that a non exchange recipient system would get from the message header.

I've tried:

```
CreationTime();

PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30070040").ToString(); //MAPI creation time

.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30080040").ToString(); //MAPI last modification time

.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040").ToString(); //MAPI Date Message Delivered
```

But none of them match the actual Date: that appears in the header on the recipient end. Taking into account timezones, etc. the Date field is a couple of seconds off.

Any ideas on how to access the date of a sent item as it appears to the clients? I would have expected date of delivery or date of creation to match.

Answer (score 1):

Try PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00390040`). Also keep in mind that OOM always rounds the date/time properties to the nearest second.

Comment: Thanks for that but they don't appear to match.

*CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME* on the *originating* client is: _"16/09/2015 4:16:09 a.m."_

*CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME* on a *recipient* outlook client is: _"Wed, 16 Sep 2015 04:16:18 +0000"_

The date in the header on a *non exchange/outlook mail system* is _"Wed, 16 Sep 2015 04:16:18 +0000"_

So the CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME is correct on outlook installs that the email didn't originate from but incorrect on the originating client.

Comment: What do you see in OutlookSpy (http://dimastr.com/outspy/) when you click IMessage? Keep in mind that the dates are rounded in the Outllook Object Model. You will need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption to get the actual data.

Comment: PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME seems to be the correct option from outlookspy, however http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00480040 isn't a valid schema reference.

Comment: I have never seen PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME property available on received messages. What do you mean by "isn't a valid schema reference" ? Do you use the "`http://`" prefix? The full DALS name must be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00480040`.

Comment: Sorry I just got back to it now. If I look at: .PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00480040").ToString() the date appears correct on a very small subset of messages.

Comment: Are you saying it is not correct on a larger subset of messages? What is the difference?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that - but I haven't done a big enough sample to be confident. As was said earlier I did at one point get an invalid schema reference.

Comment: You mentioned that PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME isn't available on recieved messages, is it always available on sent? I can get the date from received messages by the transport header.

Comment: I have never seen PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME sent on any messages. Do you see that property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage)?

Comment: Yes, and I'm getting a date off of it at runtime as well. It appears to be the only correct date.

What I have found is that its only available on sent items that I have sent, for instance its not available on items inviting users to an office 365 document which was automatically created, its also not available on received mail. There's not a lot of information on PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME so I'm worried that it's not set on self hosted exchange systems.

Comment: It turns out PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME only exists if the email is sent by outlook so its not something that we can rely on.

It appears as though this problem is not solvable in this way.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME. Are you trying to compare  values on the sender and recipient machines? That will never work since the clocks are never in sync.

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest Dmitry, I'm looking to match the date between clients, however I'm looking at doing it based on the date that is in the transport header, the date is put in there by the transport agent and matches PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME but not PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME. So I want the date that is hard boiled into the email when its sent, not the local date from the clients. On recieving an email you can look at the transport header and get the date, but it looks like you can't get it from a sent email.

Comment: As a general rule, the sending client only populates the Date MIME header.

Comment: Although in the case of exchange it seems that the MTA sets the DATE MIME header, and that corresponds to  PR_PROVIDER_SUBMIT_TIME which is only available for outlook sent messages. PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME seems to be off (curiously it appears to be set AFTER the DATE mime field). This is taking into account possible timezine differences.